# React Hooks reversing syntax of useState - pretty strange

Tags: reactjs, syntax, state, react-hooks

So I've used React Hooks somewhat heavily in the past few months on one particular project - this is the first time I've seen anything like this and was wondering if anybody had an explanation as to what is happening.

I have the following:

```
  const [ setSectionDefects, sectionDefects ] = useState([]);
  const { propertyDefects, propertySections } = props;

  useEffect(()=> {
    const defectsBySection = [];

    propertySections.map(propertySection => {
      const sectionId = propertySection.SectionId;
      const defectArray = [];
      const sectionObject = { id: sectionId, defects: defectArray };
      propertyDefects.map(propertyDefect => {
        if (propertyDefect.WosectionId == sectionId) {
          defectArray.push(propertyDefect);
        }
      })
      defectsBySection.push(sectionObject);
    }) 

   // setSectionDefects(defectsBySection);
   // sectionDefects(defectsBySection);
  }, []);

  console.log(setSectionDefects, sectionDefects)
```

When the code reaches the console.log statement, it says that 'setSectionDefects' is an array and 'sectionDefects' is the function to set it!

My mind is blown, I can't figure it out for the life of me - the syntax, as I've learned it, is the function declaration first, and then the variable to be set -

ie: const [ setSectionDefects, sectionDefects ] = useState([]);

Has anyone else ran into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first item in useState is the state itself and and second item is function to update it.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate.

In your case just swipe the names.

```
const [ sectionDefects , setSectionDefects] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have array destructuring the wrong way around.

It should be:

```
const [ sectionDefects, setSectionDefects ] = useState([]);
```